# Using \pause with Feynman diagrams in Beamer

Tags: beamer, feynmp-auto

When using Beamer (for a presentation), Feynman diagrams (created with Feynmp-auto) don't appear to work with `\pause` or `\uncover`, the diagrams are just there from the start of the slide. However both of these commands work with text/equations so it must be something to do with the Feynman diagrams.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=50]{Radiative corrections}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{complicated}
\uncover<2>{
\begin{fmffile}{Feynmanparameters}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(150,80)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o2,o3}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1}
    \fmf{plain}{v1,v2}
    \fmf{fermion}{v2,v3}
    \fmf{plain}{v3,i2}
    \fmf{fermion}{o2,v5}
    \fmf{plain}{v5,v4}
    \fmf{plain}{v4,v6}
    \fmf{fermion}{v6,o3}
    \fmf{photon}{v2,v4}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{photon,left=0.5,tension=0.2}{v1,v3}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The Feynman diagrams are being generated externally, in metapost, and then imported as a graphics file, så `\pause` doesn't have a chance to work.

Comment: I thought that might have something to do with it, is there any way to get it to work?

Comment: You could use Ti*k*Z for the graphs, it as excellent beamer integration.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this by using the `only` command - I'm not sure why it worked though!

New code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{\usetheme{Warsaw}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=50]{Radiative corrections}
\includegraphics[width=5cm]{complicated}
\only<2>{
\begin{fmffile}{Feynmanparameters}
\begin{fmfgraph*}(150,80)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o2,o3}
    \fmf{fermion}{i1,v1}
    \fmf{plain}{v1,v2}
    \fmf{fermion}{v2,v3}
    \fmf{plain}{v3,i2}
    \fmf{fermion}{o2,v5}
    \fmf{plain}{v5,v4}
    \fmf{plain}{v4,v6}
    \fmf{fermion}{v6,o3}
    \fmf{photon}{v2,v4}
    \fmffreeze
    \fmf{photon,left=0.5,tension=0.2}{v1,v3}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make the answer more explicit?